# Why am I getting this JspException?

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone explain this exception and its cause:

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property: "loanInfoSearch_dto.branchCode" of bean: "org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorActionForm"

Comment: Could you show us your code snippet / info that can help us help you?

Comment: ok, i already solved it.  the form name in jsp page was wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but if you've got a class named `LoanInfoSearch_dto` and you've got an instance of it named `loanInfoSearch_dto`, and it has a private variable named `branchCode`, then you're missing a method named

```
public T getBranchCode() {
   return branchCode;
}
```

where `T` is `branchCode`'s type. From its name, I'd assume its an `int` or some other numeric type.

Comment: thanks. i wrote the method but there was a typing mistake in form name in jsp page. thanks.